# pass parameters in reflection C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i have such code

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(@"d:\0.bmp");
tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
ocr.DoOCR(b, Rectangle.Empty);
```

the i try to make it through reflection

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("tessnet2_32");
Type myType = a.GetType("tessnet2.Tesseract");
MethodInfo mymethod = myType.GetMethod("DoOCR");
Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
mymethod.Invoke(obj, null);
```

how can i pass parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mymethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] { b, Rectangle.Empty });
```

Comment: hmm
now i have exceprion 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
can you explaine why? method is working well if a call it without reflection

Comment: Maybe DoOCR is overloaded, try to get more specific method with: myType.GetMethod("DoOCR", new Type[] { typeof(Bitmap), typeof(Rectangle) });

Comment: Sorry, that idea with overloading is wrong, in this case exception should be thrown on GetMethod line.

Comment: Check the innerException of the thrown exception to see whats going on

Comment: Also make sure that b is not null before passing it

Answer (score 1):

that would be through the `MethodInfo.Invoke(obj, object[] parameters`) method

so `myMethod.Invoke(obj, new object[] {b, Rectangle.Empty});`